# Issue registering proxy in a new EOS enviroment

Tags: cleos, system-accounts

I just setup a new instance of EOS.
I loaded all the system contracts (system, bios, msig, wrap ...) without problems, but when I call the proxy actions:

```
cleos system regproxy
cleos system voteproducer proxy
```

I get the following errors:

```
Failed with error: Assert Exception (10)
!action_type.empty(): Unknown action voteproducer in contract eosio
 Failed with error: Assert Exception (10)
!action_type.empty(): Unknown action regproxy in contract eosio
```

My environment:

- ubuntu 18
- eos 1.8.1
- cdt 1.6.1
- sys contracts 1.6.1

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it myself. The issue was with the order of setting up the system contracts. The `eosio.bios` contract must be set before the `eosio.system` contract. Then everything worked

Comment: Also keep in mind you need to have over 150M tokens staked before the testnet will be considered active. There is an error message that claims it must be 15% of total tokens, but that is incorrect if you choose to create less than 1B tokens.

https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/issues/291